# Which library is most ideal for handling web sockets in Python 3?

Tags: python, node.js

I am developing an instant messenger, and while the client will be communicating with the server via JavaScript (because it is a web-application), I decided to go with Python for the server backend. I was wondering which library would be most ideal for handling and verifying client requests, as well as sending client requests to other clients to enable instant messaging. I considered AJAX polling, but that is terribly inefficient for instant messenging.

So far, the two libraries I've considered (considering I want to make use of Asyncio) are:

- Tornado
- Websockets (wish they renamed their library because whenever you look up python 3 web sockets it's all you see)

Which library would you suggest as a backend for an instant messenger? Or, would you suggest not using Python at all, and going with a language more traditional, such as Node.JS? The reason I am picking Python is because I have a decent background in asynchronous programming with Python, as I have just recently developed an asynchronous socket server.